# Why can't I catch the error with PDOException?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, error-handling

Get info passed by POST method, and trim all space in the string, then start a new pdo instance, connect mysql, and insert info passed by POST into table.

```
$title = trim($_POST["title"]);
$content = trim($_POST["content"]);

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog";
$con = new PDO($dsn,"root","xxxx");

$title = $con->quote($title);
$content = $con->quote($content);

try
{
    $sql = "insert into tmp (`title`,`content`) values('$title','$content')";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException  $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The above is my PHP code to make the job done,the most import command is

```
insert into tmp (`title`,`content`) values('$title','$content')";
```

No error info is shown by running the above PHP code, and no error exists in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`, but info has not been inserted into the database.

I changed the

```
insert into tmp (`title`,`content`) values('$title','$content')";
```

into

```
insert into tmp (`title`,`content`) values($title,$content)";
```

The info passed by POST can be inserted into mysql now, the issue that confuses me is  that:

1. `echo $e->getMessage();` take no effect at all.
2. no error info in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

How can I catch these errors?

Comment: Try adding http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: I would not recommend that `quote` function. You should parameterize the query. Per the manual, `prepared statements with bound parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL injection, but are often much faster to execute than interpolated queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form of the query.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you are trying to catch will never be thrown, because you need [to tell PDO how you want it to handle errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

```
$con = new PDO($dsn,"root","xxxx");
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Otherwise, the default `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` will be used:

> This is the default mode. PDO will simply set the error code for you to inspect using the PDO::errorCode() and PDO::errorInfo() methods on both the statement and database objects; if the error resulted from a call on a statement object, you would invoke the PDOStatement::errorCode() or PDOStatement::errorInfo() method on that object. If the error resulted from a call on the database object, you would invoke those methods on the database object instead.

Tangentially, you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). You are using a `prepare()` call, but you are not parametrizing the query and binding the variables as you should. Using `quote()` is not secure enough.

---

### 2020 Update:

Interestingly, starting with PHP 8, the default behaviour for PDO will change and will throw exceptions by default. The change was voted on [this RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pdo_default_errmode), which mentions:

> The current default error mode for PDO is silent. This means that when an SQL error occurs, no errors or warnings may be emitted and no exceptions thrown unless the developer implements their own explicit error handling.
>
> This causes issues for new developers because the only errors they often see from PDO code are knock-on errors such as “call to fetch() on non-object” - there's no indication that the SQL query (or other action) failed or why.

When PHP 8 is released on November 2020, the default error mode will be `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.